# Angular 2 @Output is not being triggered in parent

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a simple todo app that shows a list of todos. When you click on one, it shows more details and sets a selected state on the row. On the new details window, I added a close button. On click, it should close the details window and remove the selected state on the todo list. It's successfully closing the todo window, but is not resetting the state on the todo list.

List:

```
@Component({
    ...
    directives: [[TodoDetailComponent]],
    ...
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    public todos: Todo[];
    title = 'List of Todos';
    selectedTodo: Todo;
    newTodo: string;

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {

    }
    ...

    todoClosed(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.selectedTodo = null;
        console.log('here');
    }
}
```

list.html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{title}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="newTodo" placeholder="New Todo"/>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="addTodo()">Add</a>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <div *ngFor="let todo of todos"
                           (click)="onSelect(todo)"
                           (todoClosed)="todoClosed($event)"
                           [class.active]="todo === selectedTodo"
                           [class.list-group-item-success]="todo.completed"
                           class="list-group-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.completed" />
                            {{todo.task}}
                            <span class="badge glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <todo-detail [todo]="selectedTodo"></todo-detail>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

detail

```
@Component({
    selector: 'todo-detail',
    templateUrl: 'app/todo/templates/detail.html'
})

export class TodoDetailComponent {
    @Input() todo: Todo;
    @Output() public todoClosed: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    closeTodo(todo: Todo) {
        this.todoClosed.emit({
            value: todo
        });
        this.todo = null;
    }
}
```

detail.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngIf="todo">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="pull-left panel-title">
            <label>id: </label>{{todo.id}}
            <span class="success glyphicon glyphicon-check" *ngIf="todo.completed"> </span>
        </h3>
        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus" (click)="closeTodo(todo)"> </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="todo.task" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.routes

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from './todo/component/list.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'todos',
        component: ListComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/todos',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ListComponent} from "../../todo/component/list.component";
import {TodoService} from "../../todo/service/todo.service";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [[ListComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]],
    providers: [TodoService]
})

export class AppComponent {
    title: 'test'
}
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './main/component/app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Comment: it seems you are not using the `todo-detail` in the template, you need to use your component to get the event. `<todo-detail *ngFor="let todo of todos"` might be a good start.

Comment: I simply truncated the snippet before posting. It's in there.

Comment: "not resetting the state on the todo list." what's the 2state of the todo list"?

Comment: I added the detail.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. If I moved the event into a service, I could subscribe to the event from both of my components.

service

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../model/todo';
import { TODOS } from './mock-todos';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    @Output() public todoClosed: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    ...
    closeTodo(todo: Todo) {
        this.todoClosed.emit({
            value: todo
        });
    }
}
```

Both component constructors

```
constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
        todoService.todoClosed.subscribe(
            todo => this.closeTodo(todo)
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo

```
closeTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.todoClosed.emit({
        value: todo // todo instead of Todo
    });
    this.todo = null;
}
```

**update**

You are emitting the event from `TodoDetailComponent` but listen on some `<div *ngFor="let todo of todos" ...  (todoClosed)="todoClosed($event)" ...>` which isn't emitting the event.

Comment: I don't see a typo?

Comment: oh, I see the typo now. updated. Stilld didn't emit the event.

Comment: You are emitting the event from `TodoDetailComponent` but listen on some `<div *ngFor="let todo of todos" ...  (todoClosed)="todoClosed($event)" ...>` which isn't emitting the event.

Comment: How do I make the list component listen to events from the detail component?

Comment: What's the selector of the list component?

Comment: I'm using a router.

Comment: You can't use bindings with components added by the router. You question doesn't contain enough information. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html for how to communicate between components. If you use the router you might be able to use route parameters.

Comment: I only use the router to get to the list component. detail is a child of the list component.

Comment: If you don't provide more details there is no way to provide some guidance. You could ereate a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Some code snippets that don't allow to derive how stuff is connnected and related are pretty much useless.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include how the app is setup.